# Build a Dictionary with reduce in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce

I am trying to use the Swift `reduce` to build a dictionary from collections in Swift .
I have the following variables:

```
var _squares  : [String] = []
var _unitlist : [[String]] = []
var _units    = [String: [[String]]]()
```

I want to fill the `_units` dictionary int the following way:

- I want to iterate over every element in `_squares`
- I want to look at all the lists in `_unitlist` and filter only the ones that contain the element
- Build a dictionary that has every single element as a key and the list of lists containing such element as value.

To give you an example. If we have:

```
squares = ["A"]
unitlist = [["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "C", "F"]]
```

the expected output should be a dictionary di "A" as key and `[["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C"]]` as value.

I tried with something like this:

```
_units = _squares.flatMap { s in
    _unitlist.flatMap { $0 }.filter {$0.contains(s)}
        .reduce([String: [[String]]]()){ (dict, list) in
            dict.updateValue(l, forKey: s)
            return dict
    }
}
```

I used `flatMap` twice to iterate, then I filtered and I tried to use `reduce`.

However, with this code I am facing the following error: `Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: [[String]])]' to type '[String : [[String]]]'` that is a bit obscure to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let squares = ["A"]
let unitlist = [["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "C", "F"]]

let units = squares.reduce(into: [String: [[String]]]()) { result, key in
    result[key] = unitlist.filter { $0.contains(key) }
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution! Could you please elaborate on it a bit more?

Comment: @GiovanniGrano Of course, but what would you like to elaborate in my answer?

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language `reduce(into: [:])`

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I fully got it now! Thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys and construct the values by using `filter`.  Here is a playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit


let squares = ["A"]
let unitlist = [["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "C", "F"]]

func dictionary(keys: [String], containing values: [[String]])  -> [String: [[String]]]{
  var dictionary: [String: [[String]]] = [:]
  keys.forEach { key in
    dictionary[key] = values.filter { $0.contains(key) }
  }
  return dictionary
}

print(dictionary(keys: squares, containing: unitlist))
```